# Calculate the distance between my current location and user locations from API with Google Maps API DistanceMatrixService

Tags: javascript, angular, geolocation, ionic2

I am working on ionic2 app. What I am trying to do is calculate the distance between my current location and user locations from API with Google Maps API DistanceMatrixService and http.get.

Here i'm using an API http://abithacoirmat.com/md/api/v1/nearby, which has a list of users with latitude and longitude. I need to list the users with the distance from my current location.

```
export class AboutPage {

    public items: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http, public platform: Platform) {
        this.http = http;
        this.platform = platform;

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.http.get("http://abithacoirmat.com/md/api/v1/nearby").subscribe(data => {
                this.items = JSON.parse(data['_body']).data;

            //Destination array for google map destinations
                var destArr = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                    destArr.push({
                        lat: Number(this.items[i].latitude),
                        lng: Number(this.items[i].longitude)
                    });
                }

                Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

                    var origin1 = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

                    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
                    service.getDistanceMatrix({
                        origins: [origin1],
                        destinations: destArr,
                        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                        avoidHighways: false,
                        avoidTolls: false
                    }, function(response, status) {
                        if (status !== 'OK') {
                            alert('Error was: ' + status);
                        } else {
                            var originList = response.originAddresses;
                            for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
                                var results = response.rows[i].elements;

                                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                                    console.log(results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text);
                                    //this.items[j].distance = results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });

            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        });

    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Nearby</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content class="mapbg">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img class="thmb" src="{{item.image}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.model}}</p>
        <p>{{item.distance}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

When i try to use this code: `this.items[j].distance = results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text;`

i'm getting **Runtime Error
Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
```

to

```
}, (response, status)=>{
    if (status !== 'OK') {
```

if you use function instead of the fat arrow notation your this won't be refering to the page.

I'd recommend you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/5706293

To answer your second question: in order to display async data change your html notation like this:

```
{{item?.name}} {{item?.distance}}
```

safe navigation operator (?) checks if the data is null and then executes the rest.

Comment: The runtime error is disappeared now, but my ion-list is not getting the 'distance' value, i think i'm pushing the value after building the ion-list. How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Nearby</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content class="mapbg">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img class="thmb" src="{{item.name}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2 style="color:#fff;">{{item.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.model}}</p>
        <p style="color:#ff971d">{{item.distance}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
   
</ion-content>

Comment: change your notation like this: `{{item?.name}}` `{{item?.distance}}`

Comment: still not getting the distance value

Comment: Are you actually getting the values? Can you include your network response?

Comment: When i do console.log(this.items) after the loop, i'm getting all the the values including 'distance', but in the list 'distance' is missing, how can i refresh the list after the loop?

Comment: Try `setTimeout(()=>{},0);` below the loop to trigger change detection manually.